# String and nested structure in import/export parameters of RFC

Tags: abap, saprfc

Can import and export parameters of RFC function modules be string and nested structures ?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: it is not giving any error as of now, but wanted to know the feasibility as some scn answers sayboth that it is supported and not .

Comment: You probably tried and saw that it works. So your question is more about what those people say, can you provide the links? PS: [ABAP doc - RFC interface](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenrfc_interface.htm): "The conversion supports all ABAP data types" (not entirely true because reference types are not supported)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have nested types in RFC.

You need to create Type Table in SE11 as you wish.

You can look for [Deep Structure](https://www.saptutorial.org/create-deep-structure-abap-dictionary/).
You can look [here](https://answers.sap.com/questions/823802/rfctable-prameter-with-flat-and-deep-structure.html) for an example.

Comment: The question is about [Nested Structures](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abennested_structure_glosry.htm), which is a structure containing at least another structure ("substructure"). That's a little bit different from a Deep Structure [(link to SAP glossary)](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abendeep_structure_glosry.htm), which is a structure containing deep components i.e. explicit and implicit references (implicit ones like strings, internal tables and boxed components). But I guess it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Support for nested types in RFC was introduced with R/3 kernel release 6.10, if I remember correctly. (Could already have been 4.6D?!) So the SCN entries you found, which say it is not supported, perhaps still refer to these old releases?